# css3 translate becomes relative positioned for children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a side bar that holds 2 divs

```
<div class="sectionsContainer clearfix"><-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="leftSection pull-left">
        <p>Maor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rightSection pull-right">
        <div class="backButton clearfix">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x blueColor pull-left"></i>
            <p class="pull-left"><strong>Back</strong></p>
        </div>
        <button class="btn blueButton ng-scope" data-ng-click="openPopover()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
        <div class="popover fade bottom in">
            <div class="arrow"></div>
            <div class="popover-content">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

they both have class:

```
.leftSection, .rightSection {
     width:50%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

When I click on **Maor** element both **leftSection** and **rightSection** gets "moveLeft" class:

```
.moveLeft {
    -ms-transform: translate(-100%,0); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: translate(-100%,0); /* Standard syntax */
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

the results is that "leftSection" div go left and "rightSection" goes left and you can see only "rightSection" because they both are under "**overflow:hidden**" div.

**popover** div is:

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
max-width:276px;
padding:1px;
text-align:left;
background-color:#FFF;
background-clip:padding-box;
border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
border-radius:6px;
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
```

now when I click on:

```
<button class="btn blueButton ng-scope" data-ng-click="openPopover()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
```

the popover div get relative position to **rightSection**
I have checked it and its because the **moveLeft** using translate property

Someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the translate function is internally using a relative position to translate the elements.  And if you have an absolute positioned element in a relative positioned parent the position is relative to the parent.

So the only option you have is to move the `popover` div out of a relative positioned parent. I usually place them directly into the body:

```
<body>
    <div class="sectionsContainer clearfix"><-- Sidebar -->
        <div class="leftSection pull-left">
            <p>Maor</p>
        </div>
        <div class="rightSection pull-right">
            <div class="backButton clearfix">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x blueColor pull-left"></i>
                <p class="pull-left"><strong>Back</strong></p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn blueButton ng-scope" data-ng-click="openPopover()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="popover fade bottom in">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <div class="popover-content">...</div>
    </div>
</body>
```